# Trouble understanding asynch in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous

I think I'm having a bit of trouble getting my head around asynchronous calls in node.js

In a simple API a GET route for a user would look in the database and in the callback return the user info.

However, I have a route middleware that receives an auth token with the call and needs to find the corresponding email in my database to return the users info.

I wrote a function that looks for an email by a given token and returns the email address. The problem with this is that (after doing some research) you should not return information from an asynchronous call to avoid running the code that needs the info that you are still waiting for.

One solution to this could be to move the database lookup to the route where the email is needed. The downside to this is that I have other places where this is needed forcing me to duplicate code which is a big no no...

So should I make the database lookup synchronous? is this even possible? this seems just a dirty as duplicating code.

Or should I save the user email on the client side to send it with the call? this also seems bad since i'd like to avoid saving user info client side.

Am I missing the solution all together?

I'd like to hear your thoughts!

Simplification of my situation:

```
router.route('/firstroute/:token')
    .get(function(req, res) {
        var email = getEmail(req.params.token);
        // find and send back user info
    })

router.route('/someotherroute/:token')
    .get(function(req, res) {
        // I also need the email lookup here..
        var email = getEmail(req.params.token);
    })

getEmail: function(token) {
    // look in session database for email belonging to this token
    User.findOne({'token': token}, function (err, session) {
       // check for err
       return session.email;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to user `Promises`

```
router.route('/firstroute/:token')
    .get(function (req, res) {
        getEmail(req.params.token)
            .then((email) => {
                res.send({ email });
                // find and send back user info
            });
    })

router.route('/someotherroute/:token')
    .get(function (req, res) {
        // I also need the email lookup here..
        getEmail(req.params.token)
            .then((email) => {
                res.send({ email });
            });
    })

var getEmail = function (token) {
    // look in session database for email belonging to this token
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        User.findOne({ 'token': token }, function (err, session) {
            // check for err
            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            }
            resolve(session.email);
        });

    });
}
```

You should also read https://spring.io/understanding/javascript-promises